# Velocity editor plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, velocity

I've seen [Veloedit](http://veloedit.sourceforge.net/), which seems to have good syntax highlighting but doesn't allow tab characters in the file being edited (wtf?) and also has no understanding of HTML.

With a little bit of googling I've found [Veloecipse](http://propsorter.sourceforge.net/), which claims to build upon Veloedit and also add HTML support - <strike>but doesn't seem to be compatible with Eclipse 3.4</strike>.

Are there any other Velocity template editor plugins for Eclipse that anyone is using?

The ideal solution would have the following features:

- Syntax hightlighting of VTL
- HTML syntax highlighting as well
- Auto-complete of VTL syntax
- Allows tabs!

**Update**: see my answer below

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's an update: I've been using Veloeclipse and it works well, not sure what led to my original comment about not working with Eclipse 3.4 but I am definitely using it with 3.4 now. Veloeclipse works better than Veloedit and Velocity Web Editor, in my opinion.

Comment: The correct url for the project is: http://code.google.com/p/veloeclipse/

Comment: I've tried all the velocity plugins at this point and I can't get any of them to work correctly with custom directives.The codebase I'm working on uses directives from org.apache.struts2.views.velocity.components extensively and every usage in the template is marked as an error. Is there a way to get this to work without getting so many false-positive errors in eclipse?

Comment: Nevermind, VeloEdit handles it... Prefs > Velocity UI > List of User Directives > New

Answer (score 5):

I have installed Veloeclipse since Veloedit raised exceptions when opening the editor and it works fine with eclipse 3.5.2.

In order to install it, I had to *de*select "Group items by category" in the "Install new software..." dialog.

Comment: I just installed Veloeclipse on Indigo Service Release 1 and all is well so far.Just wanted to add that to assuage the fears of those that are balking at the "Tested on Eclipse 3.3 and 3.4" comment on the project webpage.

Answer (score 1):

just try

Velocity Web Edit

http://velocitywebedit.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

you can download Veloeclipse for Velocity Template from `http://code.google.com/p/veloeclipse/`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>According to 
http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=126011
the last release was 2006 so, I don't think that it's actively maintained anymore.</strike>

Too bad that veloedit doesn't work.

Ok, I tried it again and now it worked. Must have something to do with my installation.
So for me veloedit is the way to go :)

Next Edit:
On the next day, I got Eclipse exceptions again, when I started to use the veloedit editor. Now I'm just using a regular html/jsp editor to have at least some kind oh html syntax highlighting...

Comment: I've been using Veloeclipse and it works well

Comment: Hmm, I tried it yesterday and I got all sorts of weird exceptions when I tried to use the editor on my eclipse 3.4 But I am having some other problems too, so this may be related to this system/eclipse installation. I will give it another try.