# Velocity editor for eclipse indigo (3.7.x)

Tags: eclipse, velocity

I saw another similar question answered here - [Velocity editor plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386877/velocity-editor-plugin-for-eclipse). I checked veloeclipse, but it has not been tested on eclipse versions after 3.4. Has anyone used veloeclipse with eclipse indigo?

or

Is there another editor better than veloeclipse for indigo? among the features I am looking for, syntax highlighting and auto-complete of VTL tags would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Velocity editor plugin for Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386877/velocity-editor-plugin-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am working on Eclipse Helios and you can find velocity editor at below link.It works fine.

http://veloedit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hi please tell me where to put this JAR I tried to put the "JARs" in eclipse/plugins folder and restarted the file.Finally tried with vm and vsl files.But no use.Please help me to know more.

Comment: you can install plugin using install new software menu in eclipse help. Than copy/paste below url when prompt.   
http://veloedit.sourceforge.net/updates/

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Veloclipse on my Indigo Service Release 1 instance and everything is working famously!

Like I said, I *just* installed it, so there could be some hidden incompatibility issue waiting to pop up. But right out of the gate, it is exactly what I was looking for.

> *UPDATE - 02.01.2012*
>   It is a month later and everything is still working well. I'd recommend this plugin for anyone doing Velocity work in Eclipse.

Comment: I just wish it supported automatic tag completion, a la Eclipse's built-in HTML and JSP editors.

Comment: True. I was building email templates, so I didn't need that feature at the time. Kind of missed that requirement at the very end of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/velocity-edit/

Quote from website:

> VelocityEdit is based on Velocity Web Edit which has stopped updating since 2006 and is now incompatible with the latest Eclipse 3.7.2. So I build this to make it go on. PS: Actually I prefer not to start another project but I can't contact with the original author. If you know his email address or something alike, contact me~
>
> Since Version 1.5 I began to add features on my own will. Below is the killing features you can only enjoy in my velocity-edit version~

Answer (score 0):

Searching in the Eclipse Marketplace I've found [ep4velo](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/ep4velo/).
It seems identical to Veloeclipse, but I've installed it succesfully under Indigo:

1. Download the jar from http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/ep4velo/downloads/detail?name=com.langtags.ep4velo_1.0.2.jar&can=2&q=
2. Put this jar into the dropins folder under eclipse directory
3. Restart Eclipse and now vm files should be editable with the ep4velo editor

The project not seems to be really active... But for now I'm using it.

Comment: Hi please tell me where to put this JAR I tried to put the "JARs" in eclipse/plugins folder and restarted the file.Finally tried with vm and vsl files.But no use.Please help me to know more.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with Helios Indigo SR2... its a beautiful plugin!

I had a bit of trouble with the direct IDE update. But it worked after I copied the jars manually into the eclipse plugins & features folders. I also had to close and re-open vm files that I had open.

Some color tuning (for 'script' which was too light) might help as well... 
Eclipse Menu: Windows->Preferences->Veloeclipse