# How to highlight vm files in IDE like Dreamweaver / Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, dreamweaver

How to enable vm files (velocity) files highlighting in Eclipse &/or Dreamweaver?  I have to work with VM files at my workplace. And I can not seem to get these files highlighted in Dreamweaver...

Comment: Basically I want to make sure vm files get highlighted just like html files in dreamweaver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386877/velocity-editor-plugin-for-eclipse), and I agree, [Veloclipse](https://code.google.com/p/veloeclipse/) is the best Velocity editor for Eclipse.  You install it by doing the following:

1. In Eclipse choose Help > Install new software...
2. Copy and paste [this URL](http://veloeclipse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/update/) into the text field and press enter
3. Install the Veloclipse editor feature

Regarding Dreamweaver, I don't know of any Velocity syntax highlighting for.  But in Eclipse you can 'mount' your directory that contains your vm files without having to create a project.

1. In Eclipse create a new simple Project
2. In the project do File > New Folder
3. In the advanced section choose to 'link' this folder to a directory on your filesystem that contains your vm files.
4. Edit those files with Eclipse and Veloclipse plugin
5. Continue using dreamweaver for editing all other files.

Answer (score 1):

There's an eclipse plug-in for this: [VelocityUI](http://veloedit.sourceforge.net/)

### Installation:

1. Download the JAR file from here:[http://code.google.com/p/velocity-edit/downloads/detail?name=com.hudson.velocityweb_1.6.5.jar&can=2&q=](http://code.google.com/p/velocity-edit/downloads/detail?name=com.hudson.velocityweb_1.6.5.jar&can=2&q=%20and%20then)
2. Copy it into your **eclipse\dropins** folder.
3. Restart Eclipse
4. Create a new Eclipse project (assuming you don't already have one)
5. Copy in some .vm files
6. Double click on .vm files - you should be able to edit them and see the syntax highlighting.

Comment: How do I use it? Which file do I download? Where do I put the file? I need some instruction please/ Oh just released you are talking of Eclipse IDE. I need for Dreamweaver please

Comment: As I noted, I need for Dreamweaver too. But thanks for your answer

Comment: Thank you everyone. I always Eclipse more than Dreamweaver. It was hard to decide whom to award the bounty. I decided on the 1st person since he is the one who suggested it. Thanks everyon

Answer (score 1):

For Dreamweaver, follow Adobe's instructions [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/change-add-recognized-file-extensions.html) to edit the Extensions.txt file and the MMDocumentTypes.xml file. Put the vm extension in the right places (you need it to be treated as HTML) and you will get what you want.